# Java scanner class, reading from a file

Tags: java

How do i carry out a OR constraint in java when searching for for something.

Lets say i have a txt file and want to search the file for

car OR bike

how do i implement this?

## Anywhere in the file

Comment: Should both words be on the same line, or anywhere in the file? Is performance an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the way you phrase it, it looks like you already have the ability to already read words from the file. If that's the case, you would do this

```
if("car".equalsIgnoreCase(word) || "bike".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
    // whatever
}
```

The key here is that double bar (`||`) in there: that's a `LOGICAL OR`. That line is the as doing this:

```
boolean hasCar = "car".equalsIgnoreCase(word);
boolean hasBike = "bike".equalsIgnoreCase(word);

if(hasCar || hasBike) {
    // whatever
}
```

If you need to read words from a file in Java, there's a number of ways you could do it. I typically use `java.util.Scanner`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next();
    // add search logic here
}
```

If you need to do more than a simple search like this, you're going to have to give more context of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
boolean found = false;
while (in.hasNext())
{
    String word = in.next();
    if (word.equals("bike") || word.equals("car")) 
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) System.out.println("I FOUND IT!!!");
```

Comment: Couple thoughts: consider putting the constant first as a rule of thumb. `"str".equals(someStr)` will never throw a null pointer exception. `someStr.equals("str")` might. It won't in this case, but it's a good guideline. Also, consider using case-insensitive comparison, since you might have capital letters at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @glowcoder Yeah this is something I threw together really quick so he could get the point. And yeah next() can't return null it will just thrown an exception.